# AttributeError: Assignment not allowed to composite field “id” in protocol message object

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I'm using protocol-buffers python to assign values. but the error is generated as stated.

proto file:

```
message MovingObject{
// The ID of the object.
//
optional Identifier id = 1;

// The base parameters of the vehicle.
//
// \note The bounding box does NOT includes mirrors for vehicles.
//
optional BaseMoving base = 2;

// The type of the object.
//
optional Type type = 3;}
```

python file:

```
mo = osi_object_pb2.MovingObject()
mo.id = 12
print(mo.id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to assign an `int` to an `Identifier`. You must either change the field type to a [scalar type](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#scalar) that maps to a Python int, e.g. `int32`, or assign an instance of the `Identifier` message.

Comment: Hello. Sorry i didn't understand what is meant by assigning an instance of Identifier message. Could you please explain? I am sorry for being lame but i am completely new to this.

Comment: Fields in Protobuf messages have types, just as variables in programming languages like C or Java. As your `id` field has the type `Identifier`, you can only assign `Identifier` messages to it, not a simple `int` like `12`. See the [Protobuf Language Guide](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#specifying-field-types0) for details.

Comment: @MuhammadShaheerMunir Please upvote helpful answers and mark the (best) correct one as solution